# How to identify significant items from a correlation matrix in Python (without inner loop)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, correlation

I have built a correlation matrix output from a small test set and ended up with the following.  True values are those that are greater than a defined value (e.g. results = correlation_matrix > 0.75 )

```
[[False False False  True]
 [False False  True False]
 [False  True False  True]
 [ True False  True False]]
```

Note that I also falsified the diagonal (top left to bottom right).  I also only need half the matrix because it's a mirror top-left / bottom-right.

Is there a way/function in Numpy (or other) for me to return the row/column of values that are True?  When I use this against real data (200k rows), I need to be able to do this quickly **without** using an inner loop.  200k*200k checks will be very very slow.  I imagine there has to be a matrix/numpy/scikit.learn etc function that will provide this but I have not been able to find one.

The expected output from this would be:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 1], [4, 3]]
```

Ideally, given that this is a mirror image would be:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: So, what's the expected output for the sample?

Comment: Ahhhh - excellent point.  I'll update the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the indices with 0-based indexing, one straight-forward way would be to mask out the lower diagonal places with `np.triu` and then get the indices with `np.argwhere` -

```
np.argwhere(np.triu(a))
```

To mask out diagonal places as well, use `np.triu(a,1)`.

Another way would be to use an explicit mask created with the help of `broadcasting` -

```
r = np.arange(a.shape[0])
a[r[:,None] >= r] = 0 # Note that this changes input array
indices = np.argwhere(a)
```

Comment: Thanks - that solves the upper triangle bit for sure